# Wordpress loop only displays 5 custom post types

Tags: wordpress

Right, I been playing around with my code for a bot now, and still can't come up with a solution to my problem.
I have custom post types with custom fields and a custom taxonomy ("lieux") with different terms. 
I have created a hierarchical page to display the articles by taxonomy term : taxonomy-lieux.php
This is the code :

```
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_4">
 <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">
     <h1><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
      $i++;?>
         <div class="portfolio<?php if ( ($i%3) == 0 ) { echo ' last'; } elseif ( ($i%2) == 0 ) { echo ' two-last'; } elseif ( ($i%4) == 0 ) { echo ' very-large'; } ?>" data-thematique="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('thematique')); ?>" data-activite="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('activite')); ?>" data-niveau="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('niveau')); ?>">
                                <div class="project-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                                <div class="project-info">
                                <span class="portfolio-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">NIVEAU :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('niveau'); ?></span></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">THÉMATIQUE :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('thematique'); ?></span></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">ACTIVITÉ :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('activite'); ?></span></span>
                                      <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">Lieu : </span><span class="white"><?php echo the_field('lieu1'); ?></span></span></div><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="button portfolio-button">EN SAVOIR PLUS</a>
                            </div>

      <?php
      endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?></div> 

      </div></div>
```

Problem is : my page only displays 5 custom post types max ! I think something's wrong with my loop, does anybody know what ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the number of posts displayed in Settings | Reading, or you can modify the current page query with:

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=-1' );
```

-1 will show all posts, or you could put another number in there if you want.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help ! I'm affraid I had already tried changing in the backend the number of posts to display but that did not change anything, that's why I think something's wrong with my loop. I also tried the page query but it did not work ! :(